# Suggestions for additional data in the data dump

Tags: feature-request, data-dump

I have a few nice to haves for the data dump:

1. Put the gravatar hash in the users.xml dump file.
2. Identify badges by ID like vote types are. Create another dump file for badge types that includes the name and the medal type.
3. Create a dump file for vote types.

I know 2 and 3 can be gleaned from either the readme.txt file or the site itself but for automation reasons it would be much easier not to have to update the types by hand.