# What are the displayed and maximum uploaded profile picture sizes?

Tags: support, profile-picture

I am going to make a new avatar, but upload it directly using the new upload feature.  I didn't see any information about the allowed sizes.

What is the maximum size, in pixels and bytes, for uploading.  In addition, what are the displayed sizes, in the user card on each post and in the user profile?

Comment: 32x32 on the post, 64x64 on the card, 128x128 on your profile.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The new upload feature, yes.

Comment: @Slurpee: "Gravatar" is an external service, so I removed the references to gravatar from your post.

Comment: @Bart so that means that to have a nice looking image on all devices, you need to upload a `256x256` image.

Comment: any limit on the file size?

Comment: Feature request: Specify the size in user interface where we upload the image.

Answer (score 6):

After a bit of research, I found that user avatars mostly use the same service as post images, Imgur, by default. So I suppose that any restrictions on post images apply to avatar images. That is, only BMP, JPG, PNG and GIF are supported, with no restriction on resolutions and a maximum of 2 MiB (2,097,152 bytes) each image.

After some more research, I found that different providers may have different restrictions for file size and uploaded image resolution, but the image size remains the same regardless of where it's stored, be it Imgur, Gravatar or Facebook. When used as avatars, images have some extra info appended to the URL (Imgur for exmaple):

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/26fxJ.gif?s=328&g=1
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^
```

This is the URL of my current avatar, extracted from [my profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/350567/idebug?tab=profile) (please visit from desktop), where I think I can see the largest possible image. The original GIF that I uploaded contains only 1 frame with a resolution of 160px*160px, and it's resized to 328px.

So the conclusion I am able to make so far is that while there's a fairly low restriction on the file itself, the image won't look much better if it exceeds 328px*328px. Any bigger image will be cropped into a square and resized into multiple resolutions for use in different cases. Here's some of them:

*Note: "Side length" in pixels*

#### Desktop Theme

| Where | Side |
| --- | --- |
| Profile | 328 |
| Edit profile | 328 |
| Developer Story | 160 |
| "Users" page | 96 |
| Profile (Top-Right) | 64 |
| Post, expanded | 64 |
| Top Bar | 48 |
| Post | 32 |
| Post List | 32 |
| Recent Reviews | 32 |

#### Desktop Chat

| Where | Side |
| --- | --- |
| User profile page | 128 |
| Beside input box | 64 |
| "Users" page | 48 |
| Expanded usercard | 32 |
| Beside message | 32 |
| Room info (inside) | 32 |
| Room info (profile) | 18 |

#### Mobile Theme

| Where | Side |
| --- | --- |
| Profile | 96 |
| Chat room | 42 |
| Top-Left Menu | 32 |
| Post | 30 |

#### Miscellaneous

| Where | Side |
| --- | --- |
| DE User page | 256 |
| SE Portal User profile | 128 |
| DE Query page | 64 |
| Flair | 50 |
| Reputation League | 42 |
| "Top Users" page | 42 |

Comment: There are other sources then imgur for profileimages as well: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/302306/158100

Comment: While true, there are two exceptions: 1) Users can still choose to use Gravatar, and many users use it, e.g. [Shog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9) and [Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood), check the source of their avatars. 2) Users who create a new account choosing Facebook as their provider get their facebook profile picture as default, see example for Facebook avatar [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/303182/facebook-979848068703160). (Yes, the default display name is also different.)

Comment: Question is general on purpose, not restricted to a specific host.

Comment: I've done my best.