# I can't add a profile photo

Tags: discussion, profile-page, profile-picture

I want to add my photo to my profile page, but I can't see,

Please: look at that screenshot

[image: Upload Profile image screenshot]

After upload the image is complete, but it does not change the image.

My image properties
Kind: JPEG image 
Dimensions: 1080 × 1080 
Size: 1,136,421 bytes

OS: Mac OS X
Browser: Safari

Comment: That looks like an extremely large picture maybe start by resizing it, find reasonable sizes [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169543/what-are-the-displayed-and-maximum-uploaded-profile-picture-sizes). After you've uploaded it, did you tick-ed the *uploaded picture* option or is the green tick still on *Indenticon*?

Comment: yes i m create it new size 128x128 on my  profile image,  i try  again upload new size image when  tick-ed the uploaded picture option,  and other   try it different browser without of safari but i see same problem ,  now I've noticed that my question post, I have added screenshot pictures to the article in  that does not appear

Comment: I can see your screenshot fine. Is imgur.com maybe blocked on the network you're on? Or a virusscanner?

Comment: thank you  rene again, i m understand now problem my country government block it this domain imgur.com :) why i dont know but 2. day after i m at india i will try again :)  thank you  again for your help, i m write 2 day  after here  my result

Comment: hi @rene now i m at india :) now not have any problem :) i see all image now  is okay thank you best regards