# Missing ProfileImageUrl for many profiles in StackOverflow data dump

Tags: support, data-explorer, data-dump, profile-picture

I noticed that in the StackOverflow data dump many profiles miss the ProfileImageUrl column.

What is the reason for this, because I could still get this data by scraping all profiles that I am interested in, but I guess that is not something StackExchange would want me to do (and it also takes a lot of time, which the data dump could have reduced drastically...)?

EDIT: See this query of my profile on StackOverflow: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/264578

EDIT2: In case some troll edits that query:

```
SELECT ProfileImageUrl FROM Users WHERE DisplayName = 'jabbink'
```

Result: *empty*

Comment: Weird. 1794029 users with a value, 2044242 users without a value. Can't see a pattern.

Comment: I first thought that maybe Gravatar URL's were removed, but the dump contains users with a gravatar URL (and also, if I really wanted this data, I could still scrape it, which is just counterproductive).

Comment: Wild guess: users that changed their profile picture after the (relatively recent) addition of locally-hosted profile images were added have that field blank, perhaps because the system now has different columns to track profile images?

Answer (score 1):

We directly export the `ProfileImageUrl` column from the `Users` table as is. Internally, we do not store Gravatar URLs *now*, but we used to in the past and the data basically reflects that.