# ImageURLs not returned when querying the Users table in Data Explorer

Tags: support, data-explorer, profile-picture

When I run this query on [Data Explorer](//data.stackexchange.com) for Stack Overflow:

```
select Id, ProfileImageUrl
from Users
where Id= 13
```

the `imageURL` for the user with `userID` 13 is not returned even though the user has a profile image. May I please know what am I missing here?

Comment: PS:  It turns out that 32% of all `ProfileImageUrl` entries are null. May be default Gravatar setting??  (But plenty of Gravatars are listed.)

Comment: See the very closely related: [Missing ProfileImageUrl for many profiles in StackOverflow data dump](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247032/missing-profileimageurl-for-many-profiles-in-stackoverflow-data-dump).